# running hash not in subshell within a bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to create a alternate uname with a different kernel release existing 
on the machine

hear is a snippet from the script:

```
dir=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir uname.XXXXXXXX)      
cat > "$dir/latest_rhel6_release" <<EOF
2.6.32-733.27.1.el6.x86_64
EOF

cat > "$dir/uname" <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
cat "$dir/latest_rhel6_release"
EOF

chmod +x "$dir/uname"
hash -p "$dir/uname" uname"
```

the code is working except the last line:

```
hash -p "$dir/uname" uname"
```

if i will run the command:

```
hash -p "$dir/uname" uname"
```

after the script has been ran then if i can run "uname -r"

I will get the required result:

```
2.6.32-754.27.1.el6.x86_64
```

the question is how can i run hash command from the script ,but not as subshell
and effect he parent shell,from which i run the script

Comment: `hash -p "$dir/uname" uname"` has unclosed `"`. You mean you want `source` the script?

Comment: changed it to :   hash -p "$dir/uname uname"  that didn't worked

Comment: It did work? I mean you got what you're expected output? I got the same kernel version on my system here when I ran that script.

Comment: sorry i meant it didn't worked for me

Comment: its working with source , but is there other way , that i can use inside the script and run it ?

Answer (score 1):

Source the script or dot it in. Assuming `myscript` is the name of your script.

```
source ./myscript
```

or

```
. ./myscript
```

and

```
hash -p "$dir/uname" uname
```

See [Why I can't set variables in my script to the parent shell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060)